# Error when refactoring out file for node with AngularJS project

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I have the following code in the directory /base/index.js (that works as expected)

```
module.exports = angular.module('multiTenantBase', [])
  .service('Speaker', SpeakerService)
  .name;

function SpeakerService($http, $q) {
    console.log('speakerzzz');
    this.fetchAll = function () {
        var defer = $q.defer();
        $http.get('/rest/speaker').success(function (data) {
            defer.resolve(data);
        }).error(function (data) {
            console.log('rest speaker error');
        });
        return defer.promise;
    }
}

SpeakerService.$inject = ['$http', '$q'];
```

I plan on having several service and want to put each one its own directory using requires.  That is, I want to move the function SpeakerService to a subdirectory /base/SpeakerService/index.js

The following does not work.  What is the correct way to refactor out a file like I'm trying to do?  that is, I want to simplify my /base/index.js to have references to the services and have each service in it's own subdirectory of /base.

base/index.js:

```
var speaker = require('./speaker');
module.exports = angular.module('multiTenantBase', [])
    .service('Speaker', speaker)
    .name;
```

base/speaker/index.js

```
function SpeakerService($http, $q) {
    this.fetchAll = function () {
        var defer = $q.defer();
        $http.get('/rest/speaker').success(function (data) {
            defer.resolve(data);
        }).error(function (data) {
            console.log('rest speaker error');
        });
        return defer.promise;
    }
}
SpeakerService.$inject = ['$http', '$q'];
```

***UPDATE***
per @Neozaru the solution is to add the following line to base/speaker/index.js

```
module.exports = SpeakerService
```

When I run the refactored version (bottom 2 source code snippets), I get no error and no output

Comment: I don't know how to use require on client side, but apparently your are forgetting to export your speaker.
Try to add 'module.exports = SpeakerService' at the end of your speaker/index.js

Comment: Thanks @neozaru  That solved it.  This is really server side since the code above is run in a gulp script that browserify's the combined file.  It seems that the name SpeakerService is not relevant. Can you explain how that impacts (or how I should do different)

Comment: In the "usual" way of dealing with multiple files, the browser loads either each file independently, either a minified file aggregating all the files. In both cases, top-level functions from a file are accessible from another.
With requirejs, each file has it's own scope and everything is private until your export it.
The new line tells require that the module 'speaker' IS the function SpeakerService, so you can use it using : require('./speaker').
When registering an angular 'component', only the token you give to it is relevant for injecting it later (here the string 'Speaker')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@see inline comment "UPDATE" for solution.